# Push notifications error "Missing registration" firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, post, request, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im trying to send push notifications from my firebase functions and i get this error "Error=MissingRegistration"

i tried using postman and it works perfectly, but when firebase run my js function it doesnt work.

This is my JavaScript Code:

```js
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "key="+key);
  let res = {'notification': {
    'title': 'Test',
    'body': 'Notificación enviada desde Firebase'
   },
   
   'to':token,
   
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhttp.responseText)
   }
  };
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to Firebase documentation error:MissingRegistration is returned when you have a Missing Registration Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)
I would recommend that you check if token value is what you expected and not null, in the cloud function

```
let res = {'notification': {
                'title': 'Test',
                'body': 'Notificación enviada desde Firebase'
            },

            'to':token,

        }
```

Comment: im using token as a constant so the token value its fine, but thanks for the answer